# Why does WPF use HTML/HEX Colors?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Why:

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAC896"></Setter>
</Trigger>
```

and not:

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="50 50 50 255"></Setter>
</Trigger>
```

?

Is this for performance reasons of the Xaml parser/compiler?

Reason I ask is, it's really difficult for artists to design an interface when they are used to RGB and/or HSV colors.

Btw I use VS 2010 WPF Editor.

Answer (score 7):

If you're an artist, you should really be using [Expression Blend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Blend). It will give you a very nice color picker, and it will handle the correct color codes for you. Also, the HEX number you provide is in the form of RGB. Two bytes of RED, two bytes of GREEN, and two bytes of BLUE.

To answer your question, someone from the WPF Design team would have to say, but I suspect it was used to keep some consistency with HTML.

As far as I know there is no difference between a HEX number, and a decimal number, they are all constants and have equal performance, since they are all represented as binary numbers in the computer.

Comment: Thanks I have heard about Expression Blend, but never used it. I guess you can't both make the UI and code, right? Because I generally go that, design some of the UI, hook certain things and then add more, but without some code, the UI doesn't work the same. Also if you think colors in RGB, you still have to use some sort of calculator to convert, right? If I could do it in my head easily, I guess that would be understandable.

Comment: You can open a project in both VS and Blend.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it is for performance, it is probably just due to HTML conventions.

Anyway, if you are dealing with hex values you can mentally separate the components of the Hex color:

FA C8 96

And they "eyeball" them as values between 0 and 255 by knowing that there are 6 extra digits A (10), B (11), C (12), D (13), E (14), F (15).

Or just copy-and-paste the hex value into a 3rd party color picker...

Comment: So FA is 150? (15*10) I am not knowledgeable in HEX values.

Comment: No, FA is `(16 * F) + (0 * A)` = `(16 * 15) + (1 * 10)` = `250`. This is because F is in the 10's place (but we are in Hex so it is 16) and A is in the one's place. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, not too much. I don't know where you got 16 and 0?

Comment: 16 is because it is hexidecimal (base 16).